# How to change the chapter name from Chapter to Module in Memoir documentclass?

Tags: memoir

I want chapter name Chapter to be replaced by Module in Memoir document. Any suggestions to achieve this.

Comment: Try `\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{Module}`

Comment: Depends on whether you are using `babel` or similar

Comment: Sorry, this did not work.

Comment: @AnandaMurthy please show a full but minimal example. As mentioned above the solution depends on the packages you use, of which you share no information.

Comment: I am creating the document using LyX. I inserted \renewcommand*{\chaptername}{Module} in the Preamble.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @AnandaMurthy As Lyx to save the document as Portable LaTeX (I think that is still a thing in Lyx, haven't used it in a while). Then from that Portable file, update your question with at least the data from the start of the document until `\begin{document}`. As you can see more and more comenters are are asking for code. Without it we cannot help as you could be doing all sorts of things in your document.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Module}

\chapter{Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @daleif Thanks for your notification, updated...

Comment: Thanks. This worked when I used Texmaker. I am unable to find out how to make it work in LyX.

Comment: I added the following lines in the preamble in LyX: \usepackage{babel}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\chaptername}%
    {Module}%
}. After this it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved it...